# CardView and LinearLayout with TextView children not displaying at all

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I've been trying to write some dynamically generated layout code for a simple app I came up with. I want to display a vertical row of cards, each on containing an undefined number of vertically aligned text boxes.

I wrote the code to generate these and populate the text, but it doesn't appear to be working and I can't figure it out for the life of me.

I'm new to Android Studio, and Java is still relatively fresh to me as well, so I could well be missing something quite obvious here.

I've tried using a few different types of View in A. Studio, and so far most work by themselves, but none can be contained within a card which would be ideal for me. Dynamically creating and editing properties of textViews works fine, but once I include the card view they no longer appear using the exact same code.

```
    //Define Params
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    params.setMargins(left,top,right,bottom);

    //Add a card for each ingredient
    for (Ingredient ing : ingredients)
    {
        CardView card = new CardView(this);

        CardView.LayoutParams cardParams = new CardView.LayoutParams(CardView.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 200);
        card.setLayoutParams(cardParams);

        card.setRadius(15);
        card.setPadding(25,25,25,25);
        card.setElevation(10);
        card.setMaxCardElevation(30);

        card.setBackgroundColor(Color.DKGRAY);

        //Make a grid for each card, text on the left, image on the right
        LinearLayout linearLayoutInCard = new LinearLayout(card.getContext());

        LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParamsInCard = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        linearLayoutInCard.setLayoutParams(layoutParamsInCard);

        card.addView(linearLayoutInCard);


        for(int x = 0; x < 3; x++)
        {
            TextView textView = new TextView(this);
            textView.setLayoutParams(params);
            textView.setPadding(left, top, right, bottom);
            textView.setTextSize(15);
            textView.setElevation(11);
            textView.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
            linearLayoutInCard.addView(textView);

            switch (x)
            {
                case 0:
                    textView.setText(ing.name);
                    break;
                case 1:
                    textView.setText(ing.price);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    //textView.setText(ing.calories);
                    break;

            }

        }
```

I'm expecting a vertical row of cards with text boxes vertically aligned withing them, each with their own content (this whole script will only make one card for now, but that's a data driven thing) yet when I run the application, I get nothing but a blank screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before venturing much further...this could be an example of the XY Problem.

Maybe have a look at the RecyclerView option?

RecyclerViews are entirely designed to manage the UI look and responsiveness of changing/scrolling data sets.

They can be a bit "what the heck" at first...but once writing them a few times, your UI look and code base is a lot more efficient and clean.

[RecyclerView example Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Vyqz_-sJGFk)

Comment: I had a brief look at RecyclerViews earlier but I couldn't really figure them out, but I'll use that video and try again, so thanks for that.